# SQL Server 2012 cache system?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cache, query-cache

I have an application that uses SQL Server 2012.

Even if I change a value directly in the database (not via an application), it takes time until the application sees those changes, even if the application selects again and again from the db.

Is there any cache system configured by default?

Is there a way to save all select queries and the results that SQL Server returns for each query?

Maybe that application cache?

Comment: You should add more details about your application, probably your application uses a cache, not SQL Server.

Comment: @McNets maybe,but it java 3party applicaion so i dont know much about it.  That why I want to know how can I save and watch all select query and watch the results after that, so I can watch witch resuals sqlserver return each time

Answer (score 1):

Nopel, no, no caching.

Let's get into detail:

> Even if I change value directly at db (not via application),

So, you use a hex editor and change the database file and expect that to work? EVERYTHING ELSE IS USING AN APPLICATION. Now, you likely mean using SSMS - but that is an application, and your quesition totally assumes we know what you think. And you do not say which application.

> it take time until the application saw those changes,

No, it does not. FUnny configuration aside (which would make it faster), a query sent after the changing transaction is committed will read the changed valur.

> even if the application select again and again the db.

Which it probably does not, you only think it does. Time to go into the code and see where the programmer has put in a caching layer that is misbehaving.